# Adding a div to the after all the particular child class divs using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have certain divs like this

```
<div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child1</div>
        <div class="child">child2</div>
        <div class="child">child3</div>
        <div class="child">child4</div>
        <div class="child">child5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to add a div as a child to parent div after all the child class divs..

Comment: `$('.parent').append('<div class="child">child6</div>');`  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **JQuery's** [Append Method](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
$('.parent').append('<div class="child">child6</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child1</div>
        <div class="child">child2</div>
        <div class="child">child3</div>
        <div class="child">child4</div>
        <div class="child">child5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery appendAfter method https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ to insert after the last div of class `child` in div of class `parent`

```js
$('.parent').find('.child').last().appendAfter($('<div></div>'))
```

You will have to adapat it if there are more than one div with class `parent`.